# My condition is not working on y dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that I want to test a condition in Column E:

What I want ? : I want to return a boolean only when values in column E equal 'test' or 'train'

What is the problem ?: When value equal 'draft' it return false but it should not return something. How to make it return nothing

Here is the code :

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'B': pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
                    'E': pd.Categorical(["test", "train", "draft"])
                    })

df2
```

#### output:

```
    B           E
0   2013-01-02  test
1   2013-01-02  train
2   2013-01-02  draft
```

#### Here is the function

```
def TrouverLesTest(x):
    if(x=='test'):
        return True
    elif(x=='train'):
        return False
```

#### execution

```
TrouverLesTest_V=np.vectorize(TrouverLesTest)
df2['E_Det']=TrouverLesTest_V(df2['E'].values)
df2
```

#### output:

```
    B            E      E_Det
0   2013-01-02  test    True
1   2013-01-02  train   False
2   2013-01-02  draft   False
```

line 2 in column E should not have the value False as E equal 'draft'

Thanks for your helps

Comment: `df = df.assign(E_det=df['E'].map({'test': True, 'train': False}))`

Comment: I would like to use np.vectorize(TrouverLesTest)  please because In the futur other type of data

Comment: It's just as easy to add them to the dictionary as it would be to add them to your function. This is the way

Comment: Can you please show the way with np.vectorize

Comment: I don't recommend you use that

Comment: If you want to use a numpy function, use `numpy.select`

Comment: I see why you don t recommend it ? even though can show please  to apply it